# How do I obtain the "Private Key" from my Armory Paper Backup

Tags: private-key, armory, paper-wallet

1) My laptop with Armory and bitcoin has been stolen.  However, I have a Paper Backup - which gives:  Wallet Version / Wallet ID / Wallet Name / Backup Type / Root Key (72 letters) - but NO "Chain Code" nor "Private Key".
2) When I try and sweep the lost wallet into Armory on another computer it asks for the "Private Key" - which, as I indicate above, is not given in the Paper Backup.  I have tried inserting the 72 Root Key letters but this does not work.

I should be most grateful if you could help.

Many thanks, in anticipation
Duncan Black